# How do you get task failure reports from firebase using the unity editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase

I'm following the docs and using this block:

```
auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(
  task => {
    if (!task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted) {
      // User has been created.
    } else {
      // User creation has failed.
    }
  });
```

I know that the creation has failed but I'm trying to figure out why. I tried

```
print(task.exception.message.tostring())
```

And it tells me System.Aggregate exception was thrown so then I check the inner exception and when I do ToString() it just says FirebaseException. If I check the message or the data of that firebase exception there is nothing. How do you get the error information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/D6KpMSYeZyw

Found my answer:

"Auth's implementation is stubbed out on the desktop.  We're going to be improving it shortly with a stub that doesn't throw exceptions but it will still not actually contact our backends."